# Excel Add-in - An unexpected error has occurred - There was an internal error while processing the request

Tags: .net, office-js, excel-addins

I am creating an Excel Add-in for my project, where a list of data has to be binded to a cell as a dropdown. When i tried to use the existing code for binding it , it reverts back with the **RichApi.Error**

I had created Excel Addin Project with Visual studio 2017. In Home.Js file, Using document.ready function() for binding the list of values in a cell.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    let range = sheet.getRange("A2:C2");
        range.dataValidation.clear();
        range.dataValidation.rule = {
            list: {
                inCellDropDown: true,
                source: "Option1, Option2, Option3"
            }
        };
     return ctx.sync();
     });
     }
 )};
```

Expected Behavior :- Binding dropdown list to a cell

Current Behavior :- GeneralException: An internal error has occurred. at Anonymous function

**Environment :**

```
 Host [Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.] : Excel 2016
 Office version number : office Professional Plus 2016  16.0.4849 - 64 bit
 Operating System :  Windows 10
 Office Js version : Microsoft.Office.js.1.1.0.16
```

Kindly help on this folks...

Comment: Looks like Jira ticket rather then a question.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Data Validation APIs are part of the ExcelApi 1.8 Requirement Set. This Requirement Set is not supported on non-subscription Office 2016. It is supported on subscription Office (Office 365) Version 1808 (Build 10730.20102) or later. For more information about the Excel Requirement Sets, see [Excel JavaScript API Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets).